# Comparing like values in a list of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list of tuples like in the example below. How can I go through list and find all the abbreviations that are the same and then add there scores up. Want to be able to do this for all the abbreviations.

```
loop = [('MD', 0.0), ('MD', 0.0), ('MD', 0.0), ('LA', 0.0625), ('LA', 0.0625), ('CA', -0.5), ('CA', -0.5), ('CA', -0.5))]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with [itertools.groupby()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> loop = sorted(loop, key = lambda x:x[0])
>>> {k:sum(list(e[1] for e in v)) for k, v in groupby(loop, lambda x:x[0])}
{'MD': 0.0, 'CA': -1.5, 'LA': 0.125}
>>>
```

---

To get average, replace the above code with below:

```
>>> result = dict()
>>> for k, v in groupby(loop, lambda x:x[0]):
...     temp = list(v)
...     result[k] = sum(i[1] for i in temp)/len(temp)
... 
>>> result
{'MD': 0.0, 'LA': 0.0625, 'CA': -0.5}
>>>
```

Comment: I assume speed is not an issue, though the log(n) overhead here seems a bit unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Counter` as another solution. This approach solves the problem with O(n) time complexity.

```
from collections import Counter

loop = [('MD', 0.0), ('MD', 0.0), ('MD', 0.0), ('LA', 0.0625), ('LA', 0.0625), ('CA', -0.5), ('CA', -0.5), ('CA', -0.5)]
c = Counter()
for k, v in loop:
    c[k] += v

print(c)
# Counter({'LA': 0.125, 'MD': 0.0, 'CA': -1.5})
print(dict(c))
# {'LA': 0.125, 'CA': -1.5, 'MD': 0.0}
```

Comment: Is there a way to divide the sum you've created by how many entries there were. Trying to get the average.

Comment: You can use another counter for capturing the number of occurrences for each item. like simply `c2[k] += 1`.